# pdfsharp combination chart with 3 series

Tags: charts, pdfsharp

I would like to create a combination chart with three (3) series: 2 bar chats and 1 line chart, plus a second y axis on the right for the line chart.

Unfortunately, my code throws an error when I try to bulid this particular type of chart.  If I create a chart with 3 identical series, or a chart with 1 bar chart and 1 line chart combined the code works alright.

Any clues please?

My code for the chart is below:

```
        Chart chart5 = new Chart();

        dt = GetChartData();

        string[] labels_Series = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        double[] Series1 = new double[dt.Rows.Count];
        double[] Series2 = new double[dt.Rows.Count];
        double[] Series3 = new double[dt.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            labels_Series[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            Series1[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][1]);
            Series2[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][2]);
            Series3[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][3]);
        }

        Series chart5series1 = chart5.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
        chart5series1.ChartType = ChartType.Column2D;
        chart5series1.Add(Series1);
        chart5series1.FillFormat.Color = Color.DarkBlue; 


        Series chart5series2 = chart5.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
        chart5series2.ChartType = ChartType.Column2D;
        chart5series2.Add(Series2);
        chart5series2.FillFormat.Color = Color.LightBlue;

        Series chart5series3 = chart5.SeriesCollection.AddSeries();
        chart5series3.ChartType = ChartType.Line;
        chart5series3.Add(Series3);
        chart5series3.LineFormat.Color = Color.DarkGray;


        chart5.XAxis.MajorTickMark = TickMarkType.Outside;

        chart5.YAxis.MajorTickMark = TickMarkType.Outside;
        chart5.YAxis.HasMajorGridlines = false;

        chart5.ZAxis.MajorTickMark = TickMarkType.Outside;
        chart5.ZAxis.HasMajorGridlines = false;

        chart5.Legend.Docking = DockingType.Bottom;

        chart5.DataLabel.Type = DataLabelType.Value;
        chart5.DataLabel.Position = DataLabelPosition.InsideEnd;


        ChartFrame chartFrame5 = new ChartFrame();
        chartFrame5.Location = new XPoint(505, 300);
        chartFrame5.Size = new XSize(450, 250);
        chartFrame5.Add(chart5);

        chartFrame5.Draw(graph);
```